# How do you keep Rails 4 test db in sync?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, rails-migrations

I have:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
```

but when I change my dev db with a new migration I get:

```
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

    bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

and when I try that it assumes the test db is blank and wants to run migration #1 but that errors.

It's like the schema_migrations tables is missing from the test db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I finally found a way around the problem:

```
 3099  rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
 3100  rake db:migrate
```

notice I ran 3099 before 3100 in `that` specific order. I have to migrate the test db FIRST, then I can migrate dev. Then my tests still run fine. If I go the other direction I get the problem described above.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to manage migrations for your test database as long as `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` is declared in your test configuration (e.g. rails_helper/spec_helper if you're using RSpec):

**rails_helper.rb:**

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

#...

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

#...

RSpec.configure do |config|
```

However, if you want to setup your test database using your `schema.rb` file then you can run `rake db:test:prepare` in lieu of running the migrations directly.

Comment: I agree I "shouldn't" need to manage migrations for test db if I have `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` but yet I still get that error. Any idea how to debug why?

Comment: Are you by chance using database cleaner version 1.4.0?

Comment: Is the timestamp in your schema.rb (ie `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: timestamp)`) the same as your latest migration?

Comment: they are in sync now but I'll try and notice next time I get this problem. thanks.

Comment: just added new migration, ran it on dev, version is correct in schema.rb but I get "ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError: 

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

 bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test" when I run rake test

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem today:

```
Rails 5.1.2
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
```

It was caused because I had a migration creating a table, and trying to create and index on a column I had renamed, so an index on [null] was appearing in the schema, which apparently the deveopment db can deal with, but the test db can't without some shenaigans involved in how the db is migrated... Each time I needed to migrate I had to run

```
rails db:drop
rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
rails db:migrate
rails db:seed
```

In order to get both the dev and test DB working to the point where I could run tests. Eventually I tracked down the index on a null column in an existing table in `db/schema.rb` it was a fairly simple matter to find the index command in the table creation migration and wipe it out. After that the DB can be brought back into form with just

```
rails db:migrate
rails db:seed
```